# Elementary proof of Jordan curve theorem for polygons

Tags: general-topology, polygons, discrete-geometry

Courant described the outline of an elementary proof of the Jordan curve theorem for polygons using the order of points:

The order of a point $p_0$ is defined by the net number of complete revolutions made by an arrow joining the point $p_0$ to an moving point $p$ as $p$ traverses the polygon $P$ once. Class $A$ is defined as the points not on $P$ with even order with respect to $P$. Class $B$ is defined as the points not on $P$ with odd order with respect to $P$.

How do you complete the proof that the polygon $P$ divides the points of the plane into two distinct domains using the above definitions?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? There are a number of points about $A$ and $B$ that has to be proven: 1) They are both non-empty, 2: $B$ is bounded while $A$ is not, 3) $A$, $B$ and $P$ are pairwise disjoint, 4) both $A$ and $B$ are connected, 5) $A\cup B$ is not connected. Did you manage to prove any of these points? Often when you outline a proof it's actually that the proof would be quite long otherwise sometimes with details to be sorted out - expanding the entire proof would be quite long.

Comment: I think Courant (and myself) did not aim for a rigorous proof. It should be similar to the one given in the book (using rays in a fixed direction and counting intersections with the polygon) and should use the following facts: 1. As long as the point does not move across the boundary the order does not change (because of continuity). 2. When the point moves across the polygon the order changes by one. Then you can use the same reasoning as in the first proof. I know that this is not a real proof, but it is intuitive. I certainly agree with your comments.

Comment: If you agree with my comment, then surely you would realize the need for addressing the questions in my comment. Using the order/winding number can indeed result in a rigorous proof (as far as polygons are concerned), but there's quite a number of steps in doing so. If you haven't tried to produce a proof then it's little use in "complete your proof" - and if you've tried to produce a proof then you should have some parts of the required results or at least some useful results already proven.

Comment: You should show what you've done so far, what results you've actually achieved. There's little use in answering such a question with pages after pages of proving stuff that you've already proven just to cover those parts that you're missing.

Comment: Note howevere using rays in a fixed direction is somewhat problematic as you have to consider the cases where the ray joins an edge or just touches a vertex. These are of course cases which could be handled, but there's some work in doing so - you must make sure that the counting is performed correctly.